# How to "nicely" detect the direct parent of a class in Perl?

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance

Note that UNIVERSAL::isa does not work for me in this case.
I do not want to walk up the inheritance tree as `__PACKAGE__->isa('UNIVERSAL')` does.

Here is an example:

```
  use 5.10.1;
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use utf8;
  {
    package Parent;
    #How to do this more elegantly?
    sub inherits_from_parent {
      no strict 'refs';
      return (__PACKAGE__ eq @{"$_[0]\::ISA"}[0]);
    }
  }
  {
    package Child;  
    use parent -norequire, qw(Parent);
  }
  package main;

  say "Child directly inherits from Parent"
    if Child->inherits_from_parent;
  #not wat I want 
  say 'Child is universal:'.Child->isa('UNIVERSAL');
```

*Is there a better way (without using `no strict 'refs';`) to detect the direct parent of a class?*
Thanks.

Comment: for simplicity here I do not check if $_[0] is an object.

Comment: It's a violation of encapsulation to want to know the details of an object's inheritance, which is why it's hard to do.  You might have a design problem, why do you want to do this?  Maybe we can figure a better way.

Comment: I have an inheritance tree. There is one class with abstract methods from which another class with less number of abstract methods inherits some functionality and adds more functionality. The second class must not be able to instantiate too. Children of this second class can have instances.

Thus some methods/functionality defined in the first(granddaddy class) must be used only in the installable classes.
To be specific:
https://github.com/kberov/DBIx--Simple--Class/blob/master/lib/DBIx/Simple/Class.pm#L267

Comment: That makes some sense, though I don't know if its worth the possibility for abuse.  [For example](https://github.com/kberov/DBIx--Simple--Class/blob/master/lib/DBIx/Simple/Class.pm#L237) this method changes its functionality depending on if its called as a class method of the semi-abstract base class or not.  Talking with rafl, this makes more sense as a role.  It's A) something which cannot be instanciated, B) implements some functionality and C) requires the user to implement the rest.

Comment: " For example this method changes its functionality depending on..." Exactly. That was the idea.
I haven't used roles yet. Will read about them more. A requirement that I put to my self is to use as much as possible what is in the core Perl 5.10.1+ distribution. That is why I needed to implement it in my class and not depend (if possible) on something else.
I posted my question here to make sure I am not too "rough" :).
Thanks.

Comment: Mouse is a single dependency, and gets you all the important functionality of Moose.  Consider that rather than writing your own OO system. :)

Comment: Oh :) I realize all that, But... hm will have to convince my self :)! Mo may do the work too :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that there is anything wrong with looking at the `@ISA` array for the class, in fact, this is what Perl does and almost certainly what any diagnostic module would do. Remember that there is nothing evil about turning off parts of `strict` when you know why you are doing it, and this is one of those cases.

To your actual question, a little Googling has yielded a few possibilities, of which Curtis Poe (Ovid)'s [`Class::Sniff`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3A%3ASniff) may be the best example.

I know that [`Data::Printer`](http://p3rl.org/Data::Printer) prints out the class hierarchy when you dump an object. Its output is meant for human readers, but you might be able to look at its code to see what it does. Again, I'm almost certain it does exactly what you do in your example!

Comment: Yes, thanks very much. Seems like wrapping it in a method is the best I can do :).